# Merge two javascript maps by comparing their keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary

i want to merge two Maps:

```
const map1 = new Map([
  [1, {title: 't1', name: 'nam1'}],
  [2, {title: 't2', name: 'nam2'}]
])



const map2 = new Map([
  [1, {value: 'v1', progress: 20}],
  [2, {value: 'v2', progress: 100}]
])



const commonMap = new Map()
```

so the new Map should look like

```
const commonMap = new Map([
  [1, {title: 't1', name: 'nam1', value: 'v1', progress: 20}],
  [2, {title: 't2', name: 'nam2', value: 'v2', progress: 100}]
])
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: what if the keys overlap? or the assumption is that they won't?

Comment: i will always have two maps which length is the same and they will have always the same keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting no one suggested this solution, but this is one other method:

```js
const map1 = new Map([
  [1, {title: 't1', name: 'nam1'}],
  [2, {title: 't2', name: 'nam2'}]
]);

const map2 = new Map([
  [1, {value: 'v1', progress: 20}],
  [2, {value: 'v2', progress: 100}]
])

const commonMap = new Map(map1);

map2.forEach((obj, k) => commonMap.set(k, {...obj, ...commonMap.get(k)}));

console.log(...commonMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the maps and reduce a new map.

```js
const
    map1 = new Map([[1, { title: 't1', name: 'nam1' }], [2, { title: 't2', name: 'nam2' }]]),
    map2 = new Map([[1, { value: 'v1', progress: 20 }], [2, { value: 'v2', progress: 100 }]]),
    mergedMap = [...map1, ...map2]
        .reduce((m, [k, v]) => m.set(k, { ...m.get(k), ... v }), new Map);

console.log([...mergedMap]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Traverse newly created `key-value` pair array from both map and set it into the new map.

```js
const map1 = new Map([
  [1, { title: 't1', name: 'nam1' }],
  [2, { title: 't2', name: 'nam2' }],
]);

const map2 = new Map([
  [1, { value: 'v1', progress: 20 }],
  [2, { value: 'v2', progress: 100 }],
]);

const commonMap = new Map();
[...map1, ...map2].forEach(([x, y]) =>
  commonMap.set(x, commonMap.has(x) ? { ...commonMap.get(x), ...y } : { ...y })
);
console.log([...commonMap]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the [Map constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) takes any iterable, you can use [a generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) that takes the maps and an optional merge strategy for values. Then iterate over the keys and use the merge strategy to combine the values. By default, you can just merge two objects:

```js
const defaultMerge = (...xs) => Object.assign({}, ...xs);

function* mapMerge(map1, map2, mergeFn = defaultMerge) {
  for (const [key, value1] of map1.entries()) {
    const value2 = map2.get(key);
    
    yield [key, mergeFn(value1, value2)];
  }
}

const map1 = new Map([
  [1, {title: 't1', name: 'nam1'}],
  [2, {title: 't2', name: 'nam2'}]
])

const map2 = new Map([
  [1, {value: 'v1', progress: 20}],
  [2, {value: 'v2', progress: 100}]
])

const commonMap = new Map(mapMerge(map1, map2));

//display for StackSnippets
for(const [key, value] of commonMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, "->", value);
}

console.log("--- custom merge ---");

const customMergecommonMap = new Map(mapMerge(
  map1, 
  map2,
  (a, b) => ({title: a.title, value: b.value})
));

//display for StackSnippets
for(const [key, value] of customMergecommonMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, "->", value);
}
```

This can be generalised for any amount of maps and the ability to handle maps with potentially different keys. Assuming the intention is to merge only existing values, then it can be done like this:

```js
const defaultMerge = (...xs) => Object.assign({}, ...xs);

function* mapMerge(...maps) {
  let mergeFn = defaultMerge;
  if (typeof maps[maps.length - 1] === "function") { //if a merge function was passed
    mergeFn = maps.pop();
  }
  
  //collect all keys from all maps in case of differences
  const allKeys = new Set(
    maps.flatMap(m => Array.from(m.keys()))
  );
  
  for (const key of allKeys) {
    const values = maps
      .filter(m => m.has(key)) //only maps with this key
      .map(m => m.get(key));   //get the value
      
    yield [key, mergeFn(...values)];
  }
}

const map1 = new Map([
  [1, {title: 't1', name: 'nam1'}],
  [2, {title: 't2', name: 'nam2'}]
])

const map2 = new Map([
  [1, {value: 'v1', progress: 20}],
  [2, {value: 'v2', progress: 100}]
])

const commonMap = new Map(mapMerge(map1, map2));

//display for StackSnippets
for(const [key, value] of commonMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, "->", value);
}

console.log("--- custom merge ---");

const customMergecommonMap = new Map(mapMerge(
  map1, 
  map2,
  (a, b) => ({title: a.title, value: b.value})
));

//display for StackSnippets
for(const [key, value] of customMergecommonMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, "->", value);
}
```